# Add/remove method vs set method in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

While using foreach with ArrayList, I know that using add/remove method will not work as it will throw concurrent modification  exception, but then why am I able to change the value using the set method within the same foreach loop ?

Here is the sample code :

```
    for (Integer integer : arr) {
        if (integer==2) {
            arr.set(1, 6);
        }
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
    System.out.println(arr);
```

If we will change arr.add() then it will throw an error, but with set it is working fine, what's the reason here ?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#fail-fast), CME is thrown if the list is *structurally modified* after the iterator is created. Since `set()` only replaces an existing element, no structural modification takes place and the exception is not thrown.

Comment: A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification. ~ Totally agree and understood. The thing is I need to read docs in more details rather than just reading which method do what work.
Thanks.

Comment: the complete sentence from the doc itself... *if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way **except through the iterator's own remove or add methods**, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.* isn't that contradictory?

Comment: The question reads .. *I know that using add/remove method will not work as it will throw concurrent modification exception but then why am I able to change value using set method* ... the `add` should've worked fine as well, right?

Comment: @nullpointer He's talking about modifying the list directly. You can only modify through the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in the implementation. When the length of the list is modified (which `add` method does) the iterator returned by ArrayList throws ConcurrentModificationException because it checks the length of the array. While the `set` method does not modify the length of the array thus no ConcurrentModificationException is thrown.